# What's the maximum possible number of eclipses(both lunar and solar) we can observe in a one year period (not necessarily a calendar year)?

Tags: astrophysics

I've seen a [website](http://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/how-many-solar-or-lunar-eclipses-in-one-calendar-year) implying that the maximum is 7, but it gives no proof.

Can we prove this result by pure calculation using known astronomical parameters?

Approximations can be applied(eg. assume the Moon's orbit is a perfect circle) as long as the calculation gives a reasonable result.

Comment: Total solar eclipses happen roughly once every 18 months, so the max would be less than one I am guessing.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Not necessarily total solar eclipses, any type of eclipse is counted.